# Reading Mongo data from Spark

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am reading data from mongodb on a spark job, using the com.mongodb.spark.sql connector (v 2.0.0).
It works fine for most db's, but for a specific db, the stage takes a long time and the number of partitions is very high.
My program is set on 128 partitions (x2 number of vCPUs) which works fine after some testing the we did. On this load the number jumps to 2061 partitions and the stage takes several minutes to process, even though I am using a filter and the document clearly states that filters are done on the underlining data source (https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/v2.0/scala/datasets-and-sql/)

This is how I read data:

```
val readConfig: ReadConfig = ReadConfig(
    Map(
      "spark.mongodb.input.uri" -> s"${mongodb.uri}/?${mongodb.uriParams}",
      "spark.mongodb.input.database" -> s"${mongodb.dbNamesConfig.siteInstances}",
      "collection" -> params.collectionName
    ), None)

  val df: DataFrame = sparkSession.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql").options(readConfig.asOptions)
    .schema(impressionSchema)
    .load()

  println("df: " + df.rdd.getNumPartitions) // this is 2061 partitions


  val filteredDF = df.coalesce(128).filter(
    $"_timestamp".isNotNull
      .and($"_timestamp".between(new Timestamp(start.getMillis()), new Timestamp(end.getMillis())))   
      .and($"component_type" === SITE_INSTANCE_CHART_COMPONENT)
  )

  println("filteredDF: " + filteredDF.rdd.getNumPartitions) // 128 after using coalesce

  filteredDF.select(
    $"iid",
    $"instance_id".as("instanceId"),
    $"_global_visitor_key".as("globalVisitorKey"),
    $"_timestamp".as("timestamp"),
    $"_timestamp".cast(DataTypes.DateType).as("date")
  )
```

Data is not very big (Shuffle Write is 20MB for this stage) and even if I filter only 1 document, the run time is the same (only the Shuffle Write is much smaller).

How can solve this?

Thanks
Nir